# React - setState in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is this legal?

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        if (typeof nextProps.contact != 'undefined') {
            this.setState({forename: nextProps.contact.forename});
            this.setState({surname: nextProps.contact.surname});
            this.setState({phone: nextProps.contact.phone});
            this.setState({email: nextProps.contact.email});
        }
    }
```

Because I don't know how to fill my inputs and still be able that the user can edit the inputs. So I came up with this solution instead of trying to manipulate the this.props.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For anyone stepping on this in 2018, you might wanna use [`getDerivedStateFromProps()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your code is legal according to [react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops).

You also may consider to put this code inside `getInitialState` method as according to [another react doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) initializing from props is not an anti-pattern.

You also can replace several calls with one `setState` method call:

```
 this.setState({forename: nextProps.contact.forename,
                surname: nextProps.contact.surname,
                phone: nextProps.contact.phone,
                email: nextProps.contact.email});
```

Answer (score 4):

As of React v16.6.3 this is considered UNSAFE and `componentWillReceiveProps` [is marked for deprecation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops). The removal is planned to happen in version 17.

> Note:
>
> Using this lifecycle method often leads to bugs and inconsistencies, and for that reason it is going to be deprecated in the future.
>
> If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead.
>
> For other use cases, follow the recommendations in this blog post about derived state.
>
> If you used componentWillReceiveProps for re-computing some data only when a prop changes, use a memoization helper instead.
>
> If you used componentWillReceiveProps to “reset” some state when a prop changes, consider either making a component fully controlled or fully uncontrolled with a key instead.
>
> In very rare cases, you might want to use the getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle as a last resort.

In your case you should use `componentDidUpdate` instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) , changing states inside *componentWillReceiveProps* is not recommended. The doc explains it very clearly.

And it also gives us alternative solutions for "fully controlled component" and "uncontrolled components", please read this [react doc](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason `componentWillReceiveProps` exists is to give the component an opportunity to setState. So yes, any state you set synchronously in it will be processed together with the new props.